# [iOS]KVO setValuesForKeysWithDictionary

Tags: ios, key-value-observing

I am using setValuesForKeysWithDictionary to populate my model object . Model object is defined as

```
@interface CommonModel : NSObject
    @property (nonatomic,copy)NSString *imageUrl;
    @property (nonatomic,copy)NSString *name;
    @property (nonatomic,copy)NSString *uuid;
    @property (nonatomic,strong)MetaDataModel *metaData;
    @property (nonatomic,copy)NSString *type;
    @property (nonatomic,copy)NSString *age;
@end
```

and I init the class as follows

```
CommonModel *model = [[CommonModel alloc] init];
[model setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:dic];
```

the dic is from the server data like

```
{
    category = random;
    created = 1436348796510;
    duration = 259;
    metadata =     {
        path = "/songs/396677ea-2556-11e5-afe1-033c8b2070b7";
    };
    modified = 1436348796510;
    name = "\U6ce1\U6cab";
    type = song;
    url = "http://www.devinzhao.com/pomo.mp3";
    uuid = "396677ea-2556-11e5-afe1-033c8b2070b7";
}
```

I knew the type should be "song" not song.

when I use [model setValue:@"type" forKey:@"type"]; It doesn't crash.

but I don't want to use like

```
[model setValue:@"type" forKey:@"type"];
```

how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Forget about using KVC and manually code an `init` method that accepts a `NSDictionary`.

You can then make any decisions about how each value in the dictionary is interpreted; for example `type` should be a `enum`, not a string, `imageUrl` should be `NSURL`, `uuid` should be `NSUUID`, etc.

Comment: the type all should be NSString

Comment: @GuicaiLi No they shouldn't, as there are better types to represent the data.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps

```
CommonModel *model = [[CommonModel alloc] init];
[dic setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",dic[@"type"]] forKey:@"type"];
[model setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:dic];
```